# Saving histograms without displaying them and adjust linewidth of plotted fit objects

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

I have a histogram with gaussians fitted in matlab. Here is my code:

```
dnbins = 100;
[counts,centers] = hist(data(:), nbins);
bar(centers, counts);
fitobject = fit(centers',counts','gauss2');hold on;
plot(fitobject,centers',counts');hold off;
```

How can I save the output, but without displaying it? Is it possible?

Also, I'd like to a have thicker red line, so I changed the following line:

```
plot(fitobject,centers',counts', 'LineWidth', 2.0);hold off;
```

I got the following error:

> Error in color/linetype argument

Whereas this piece of code works well:

```
plot(centers',counts', 'LineWidth', 2.0);hold off;
```

Of course, it doesn't satisfy me, beacuse I want to see the fitted curve as well.

How can I change the line thickness?

Edit:

I got the following error:

```
  This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option.
```

And it makes sense, because I can't use the graphical output. I complie the code and then I run it under Linux.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: you need the `'visible'` property of the `figure` object.

```
...
fitobject = fit(centers',counts','gauss2'); hold on;
figure('visible','off') 
plot(fitobject ,centers',counts'); hold off; 
...
```

Second problem: using the `plot` function with fit-objects calls actually a different [**`plot` (cfit)**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/plot.html) function, which is part of the the **Curve Fitting Toolbox**. That's why the usual behavior does not apply. This little workaround however works almost always.

```
h = plot(fitobject, centers',counts'); hold off;
set(h, 'LineWidth',2)
```